# how to add a multi column unique index in Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

the entity generator does not seem to support composite unique keys, is the suggested way to get around this just to create 1 unique field with the concatenated values maybe ? e.g.

```
pkCol uniqueMultiCol     unique_field1| unique_field2| unique_field3
1     a_b_c              a             b               c



or maybe add a liquibase migration to add the unique multi column index?
```

Comment: This is not covered by JDL, I would just write a Liquibase migration.